# echo command using c++

Tags: c++, echo

I want to issue the echo command inside a c++ file.

All i need to do is

echo "xml::/var/some.xml" >> /var/config

In C++ file, I tried,

system("echo" + "xml::/var/some.xml" +">> /var/config");

But it throws invalid operands of types const char[6] and const char[46] to binary operator +.

Need help

Comment: Your strings are `const char *`, not `std::string`. `operator+` on strings works for C++ strings. However, why are you using system to do this? You could just open `/var/config` in code and append to it.

Comment: Why not just write to a file in C++?

Comment: It seems you have multiple issues here. First off, I can see you are missing a space after the word `echo`. Why not get it working with a regular string first so you are only solving one issue at a time? And why not simply use `cout` or `printf` or write to the file directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is one where you may be able to get away with "can has codez?":

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

   std::copy(argv+1, argv+argc, std::ostream_iterator<char *>(std::cout, ""));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just output the data yourself using stdio methods `fopen`/`fputs`/etc..

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fputs

Comment: Given that it's tagged as C++, why would you recommend `fopen`, `fputs`, etc?

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
#include <string>
system(std::string("echo" + "xml::/var/some.xml" +">> /var/config").cstr())
```

you are passing raw character strings which do not support the + operator -- so try to use std::string instead.

Comment: And you're still trying to apply `operator+` to raw character strings. Plus you misspelled `.c_str()`.